# Beyond Compare 4 shows "Editing disabled" when resolving a merge from Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I used Beyond Compare 3 for years as a merge tool.  I'm familiar with how it works.

I recently installed Beyond Compare 4 (Version 4.2.6) and Mercurial uses it as the visual editing tool for resolving merge conflicts when this command is entered:

```
hg resolve --all
```

The problem is that both sides of the merge come up as read only, showing "Editing disabled" in the status bar, which makes the merge impossible.  (See screen shot)[image: Editing Disabled Message]

I have read extensively about the various configuration files for Beyond Compare and Mercurial.    I've edited multiple lines in the 'mercurial.ini' and '.hgrc' files to attempt to override this, but I can't seem to fix this behavior:

```
merge-tools.beyondcompare4.args=$local $other $base /mergeoutput=$output /lefttitle=parent1 /centertitle=base /righttitle=parent2 /outputtitle=merged /automerge /reviewconflicts /solo     
merge-tools.beyondcompare4.diff3args=$parent1 $parent2 $child /lefttitle='$plabel1' /centertitle='$clabel' /righttitle='$plabel2' /solo
merge-tools.beyondcompare4-noauto.args=$local $other $base /mergeoutput=$output /lefttitle=parent1 /centertitle=base /righttitle=parent2 /outputtitle=merged /reviewconflicts /solo         
merge-tools.beyondcompare4-noauto.diff3args=$parent1 $parent2 $child /lefttitle='$plabel1' /centertitle='$clabel' /righttitle='$plabel2' /solo
```

Does anybody have an answer for (1) WHY this behavior exists and (2) how I can fix it?

Comment: If you open Help > About Beyond Compare, are you using Beyond Compare 4 Pro or Beyond Compare 4 Standard? Standard edition doesn't support 3-way merge. If you have a Pro license, the 3 input panes are read-only, the output pane at the bottom should be read-write.